# Update Knockout `attr` binding from DOM instead of from ViewModel

Tags: javascript, html, knockout.js, html-tag-details, html-tag-summary

I am using Knockout.js to populate a set of HTML5 `<details>` elements.  Here is the structure:

```
<div class="items" data-bind="foreach: Playlists">
    <details class="playlist-details" data-bind="attr: {id: 'playlist-details-' + $index(), open: isOpen}">
        <summary>
            <span data-bind="text: name"></span> - <span data-bind="text: count"></span> item(s)
            <div class="pull-right">
                <button data-bind="click: $parent.play, css: {disabled: count() == 0}, attr: {title: playbtn_title}" class="btn"><i class="icon-play"></i> Play</button>
                <button data-bind="click: $parent.deleteList" class="btn btn-danger"><i class="icon-trash"></i> Delete</button>
            </div>
        </summary>
        <div class="list" data-bind="with: items" style="padding-top: 2px;">
            ...
        </div>
    </details>
</div>
```

The data in the ViewModel looks something like this:

```
var VM = {
    Playlists: [
        {
            name: "My Playlist1",
            count: 3,
            items: [<LIST OF SONG ID'S>],
            playbtn_title: "Play this playlist",
            isOpen: true
        },
        {
            name: "My Playlist2",
            count: 5,
            items: [<LIST OF SONG ID'S>],
            playbtn_title: "Play this playlist",
            isOpen: null
        },
        {
            name: "My Playlist3",
            count: 0,
            items: [],
            playbtn_title: "You need to add items to this list before you can play it!",
            isOpen: null
        }
    ]
};
```

I have added the ability to remember the [open or closed state](http://jsbin.com/egefop/2/edit) of the details view using the `isOpen` property of the ViewModel and an `attr` binding (As originally described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24785460/binding-viewmodel-to-existence-of-a-property-in-knockout)).

However, when I click the `<summary>` to expand the details, the ViewModel does not get updated - unlike `value` bindings, `attr` bindings aren't two-way.

How can I get this binding to update when the attribute value changes?

I know that the browser triggers a `DOMSubtreeModified` event when the element is opened or closed, but I;m not sure what I would put there - several things I have tried (including `.notifySubscribers()`, `if (list.open()) ...`, etc.) cause looping, where the property being changed makes the event trigger again, which changes the property again, which triggers the event again, etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way that I found in the end that works is simply to have the `DOMSubtreeModified` "manually" update the value:

```
$(document).on('DOMSubtreeModified', 'details.playlist-details', function(e) {
    var list = ko.dataFor(this);
    list.open(this.getAttribute('open'));
});
```

(Somehow, this does not cause the looping that more-complex constructs I tried had caused.)

Answer (score 1):

Using `$` to play DOM directly is not `ko` way :-)

Just create a two-way binding for HTML5 `details` tag, it's cheap in ko.

http://jsfiddle.net/gznf3/

```
ko.bindingHandlers.disclose = {
    init: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        if (element.tagName.toLowerCase() !== 'details') {
            throw "\"disclose\" binding only works on <details> tag!";
        }
        var value = valueAccessor();
        if (ko.isObservable(value)) {
            $(element).on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
               value($(element).prop('open'));
            });
        }
    },
    update: function(element, valueAccessor) {
        $(element).prop('open', ko.unwrap(valueAccessor()));
    }
};
```